# tomcat webservice information java

Tags: web-services, tomcat

I tried to look in Google and browse different issues here in the forum but couldn't find a solution.
I have a web-service and I want to create a method that returns information about the service and also about tomcat.
However, I couldn't find how to query tomcat.
I want to know for example on which port tomcat is listening, its JVM configuration, Memory Perm size and etc.

Thanks,
Clint

Comment: What is your requirement? You can get this information with JConsole & JMX.Try googling "tomcat monitoring JMX" and "jmx jconsole tomcat".You can use JConsole rather than reinventing

Answer (score 0):

Look for the definitions in conf/server.xml - you can see the ports and threads definition.

What is your JAVA_OPTS at startup.sh or Catalina.sh? You can add there definition for jmx flags, XMx, garbage collection flags, etc

see this as example [Tomcat jmx](http://www.gesea.de/techdocs.htm?id=67626&page=0)

Then you can also connect to your application from jconsole and see the tomcat jmx beans it is exposes.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however, I don't want to use a third party application in order to get information about tomcat. I need to show additional information besides the information about tomcat and I don't want to use multiple applications, is your suggestion relevant also for this case ?

Comment: Jconsole is standard java tool. Look at your Jdk bin package